# Prozac, Ritalin and Valium..together

Tags: medications

There is [a certain movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119642/) in which one the characters takes Prozac, Ritalin and Valium..together. When someone asks him what it is, he states the composition, adding "Breakfast of Champions".

Being totally clueless about such medicine, what would happen to someone if they took these together?